# How to make these titles more concise?

Tags: abbreviations

I have two lists. The first one is a list of some task with the title of "the tasks that I have performed in this project" and the second one is a list of some skills with the title of "the skills that I have gained in this project".
I want to abbreviate these titles into two words (actually for my CV).
Among the following options which ones are correct?

> 1)Tasks performed
> 2)Performed tasks

> 3)Skills gained
> 4)Gained skills

Comment: (1) and (3) would be more idiomatic (they have the noun and verb in the same order as in the longer versions).

Comment: It's the same principle as arises with column headings and computer input fields where the names are "related". For example, you might well see a couple of input boxes labelled ***Address line 1*** and ***Address line 2***, but you certainly wouldn't expect to see ***1 Address line*** and ***2 Address line***. Get the most important word (normally a ***noun***) in first!

Answer (score 1):

"Tasks performed" and "Skills gained" are clear, concise, explicit, and commonly understood.